# Populate data using another collection in mongoose v6.2.8

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

Im having issues populating my mongoDB collection with another collection based off the `_id`. It Keeps returning an empty object with no errors or anything?

**Property Schema**

```
const PropertySchema = new Schema({
  landlord: {
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: "Landlord",
    required: true,
  },
  ...
});
```

**Landlord Schema**

```
import { Schema as _Schema, model } from "mongoose";
const Schema = _Schema;

const LandlordSchema = new Schema({
  fname: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  lname: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  phone: {
    type: Number,
    required: true,
  },
  email: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  company: {
    type: String,
  },
});

const Landlord = (module.exports = model("Landlord", LandlordSchema));
export function get(callback, limit) {
  Landlord.find(callback).limit(limit);
}
```

**Property Controller**

```
exports.readProperty = async (req, res) => {
  await Property.find({ _id: req.params.propertyId })
    .populate({
      path: "Landlord",
      select: "fname lname email phone company",
      model: "Landlord",
      strictPopulate: false,
    })
    .then(function (err, property) {
      if (err) return res.send(err);
      res.json(property);
    });
};
```

**mongodb Property Collection**
[image]

**Mongodb Landlord Collection**

[image]

**When running the get call from postman it returns:**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this issue by selecting the field: `landlord` not `Landlord`